# How to connect docker images of ASP.NET Core (code first) and SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, docker-build, nopcommerce-4.2

I'm working with a project on nopCommerce, and trying to run it using docker images. There are two images, one is for nopCommerce and the second one is for MSSQL server. Here are the step I have followed,

1) Build docker image and run on a port 8080

```
C:\Users\Admin>docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name mystore nop420
ca626cc5ed4e3759a03e9645dcd374016a5d8f278ffede8e1345f851f9a82c7d
```

The project runs on the port 8080

2) Pulled out MSSQL(Express) Linux image from the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server)

3) Ran it using command

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Express' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
```

4) `docker exec -it unruffled_tharp "bash"`

5) `/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'yourStrong(!)Password'`

6) Created DB

7) Tried to connect MSSQL image using VSCode extension and it works

[image]

8) Passed the same connection string to the nopCommerce install page

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=nop420;User ID=sa;Password=yourStrong(!)Password
```

But it gives an error

`Setup failed: An error occurred while creating the database: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

I've tried using IP instead of localhost, adding port 1433 and almost everything from different forums though the error remains the same.


**Edit:** Here is network inspect

```
$ docker network inspect 6cb
[
    {
        "Name": "mynetwork",
        "Id": "6cb7171b74ee08a55d4ab8c9a26518bfb0a21ee5d8894300a7151453925f550d",
        "Created": "2019-07-16T01:13:46.4791178Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "ca626cc5ed4e3759a03e9645dcd374016a5d8f278ffede8e1345f851f9a82c7d": {
                "Name": "mystore",
                "EndpointID": "dbe46ebc4208bbce5d29c55c40bc0a0809ff3196da5ce7360c6e1a6771fcb7be",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ca7b383ff3d5118aa15183728084e355619eb28b47d6e60c885a9e5c5af795ba": {
                "Name": "nostalgic_northcutt",
                "EndpointID": "6ec4ae69ba2586ce432471e82dcecc94e598e9f9c18f59ef2b557a317adf4736",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually because Docker creates its own internal network for the containers and thus the two containers  do not see each other by default. So you have two options:

1. Create a docker network and attach the two containers to that network

Create a new network:

```
docker network create <networkName>
```

To connect a container to a particular network either:

–   Connect to the network when you start the container with docker run and the —network flag. Something like this (note the network flag)

```
docker run -dit --name <containerName> --network <networkName> <imageName>
```

–   Connect already created container to the network using

```
docker network connect <networkName> <containerName>
```

2. Use docker-compose to setup both your images (this is my preferred option). Docker compose automatically creates the network and sets up the containers to run in that network

Once you have set the network you should be able to reach from container to container using `containerName:PortNumber`

If the containers still cannot talk to each other:

–   Check that they both actually in the same network: by running `docker network inspect`

–   Check if the other machine can be reached (from within the container)

```
ping <dockerContainerName>
ping <dockerContainerIPaddress>
```

–   Check if the appropriate port is open

```
nmap -p <portnumber> <dockerContainerIPaddress>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give a try.

Comment: Created a network, but the issue is still there, added network inspect to the question.

Comment: How are you now trying to connect  between containers, it should be continerName:portNumber. Can you ping one container from inside the other container?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same `containername:portnumber`, but that's giving error *Setup failed: Database does not exist or you don't have permissions to connect to it*

Comment: that is odd. can you ping the db container from the app container? Both containers are now in the same network now and should be able to talk to each other.

Comment: I think I need to try with docker compose now

Comment: Yes docker compose make more sense and an easy way to run multiple images altogether!

Comment: Though, I don't know why was individual in the same network aren't working

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
What worked for me was changing (in step 8) the the `Data Source/Server` in connection string to:  `host.docker.internal`

Comment: That connects to a server running on the host, ie your machine, not in another container

Comment: Correct. And if you have a sqlServer container with the OP's setup running on your machine, from your machine you can reach it via localhost

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).